# ZFS: How does it work? Mirroring on Raid0

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, zfs

I've got a laptop, that I want to migrate to ZFS filesystem.

This laptop has 2HDD Drives.

My zpool idea is like this:

1 zpool on 2 HDD drives.

```
/ - separate subvol
/home - separate subvol with 'copies=2'
```

Will this benefit of 2 HDD drives? For example, if 1st HDD would fail, would I be able to recover the /home partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZFS does attempt to store copies on different drives according to https://blogs.oracle.com/relling/entry/zfs_copies_and_data_protection.  However, copies, from what I understand it, are to protect from data corruption in the filesystem, but are not guaranteed to be stored on different drives.  I also don't know if ZFSonLinux has included the same exact copies functionality.  RAID0, or striping, is dangerous but I'm sure you already knew that.

Your best bet is to create two different pools.  Create two partitions on each disk, make a striped zpool from one and a mirrored zpool on the other.

Comment: @mikhailkrutov: Also ZFS is not a replacement for back-ups!  Especially [system backups](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)!  With ZFS, you've been upgraded to User type 4!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

With two mirrored devices in your pool that would be fine.  If one fails you can recover the data from the second one; replace the failed one.
https://blogs.oracle.com/partnertech/entry/a_hands_on_introduction_to2

I would never recommend putting two partitions on a single disk (someone else's suggestion) except for playing about or testing.  The performance would suck, and if a drive fails then you lose two devices instead of one.